# Visual Studio Class Diagram Class File Location

Tags: visual-studio, class-diagram

I'd like to define my MVVM model classes in a class diagram, but when I add a class to the diagram from the class diagram toolbar, it always creates it at the top level of the project. (I'd like the classes to be in the \Models folder, where the diagram itself lives.)

I've tried including the folder in the class name in the Add dialog, but it won't accept the \ or / characters, and I can't think of anything else to try.

Moving the class files after the fact isn't a big deal, but then the diagram loses track of them and I have to re-create it, which is annoying.

This seems to me like it ought to be easy and obvious. Am I having a stupid day?